# Magento 2 OAuth without a Callback URL

Tags: magento2, rest-api, oauth

I need to integrate a back end application (i.e. without a GUI) with Magento 2 REST APIs. As such I believe I need to use OAuth for authentication. However, as it is a back end service, there will be no users to process any redirects to third party urls. Is it possible to authenticate via OAuth in Magento2 without going to a callback URL? I note when you register an integration the callbacks are optional, and if you leave them blank the access token and access token secret are generated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's needed unfortunately. In a nutshell to complete the process of linking site to something. Did you manage to progress by skipping this step? I would be surprised to hear if you did.

Comment: Nope I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Do you know how do applications without a GUI access Magento 2 APIs?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Script to demonstrate Oauth call with signature generation process.
[refer stackexchange link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275325/magento-2-oauth-without-a-callback-url)